# getting event data attribute in react (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how i can get data attritube and i have search some answer but it's all not working.

```
<div onClick={handlePropsClick}
     title={'aaa'}
     data-id={2}
>
   <div className='value-text'>Hello</div>
</div>

const handlePropsClick = () => event =>  {
    alert(event.target.getAttribute('data-id'));
};
```

But I get null and am expecting to get 2
So what's the best way to do this in react

from the suggestion of @Jaromanda X I try to debug and print the value of event.tartfer to console below is what I got

```
   console.log(event.target) 
    output: <div class="value-text">Hello</div> 
    which is a child element then i do 
console.log(event.target.parentNode) 
output: 
 <div  title="aaa" data-id="2">        
   <div class="value-text">Hello</div>  
</div> 
and then when i do console.log(event.target.parentNode.getAttribute)
```

Comment: debug step 1: `console.log(event.target)` to see what the target actually is

Comment: `console.log(event.target)` gives `<div class="value-text">Hello</div`> which is a child element then i do `console.log(event.target.parentNode)` which gives `<div  title="aaa" data-id="2"> <div class="value-text">Hello</div>  </div>` and then when i do `console.log(event.target.parentNode.getAttribute)` i still get null

Comment: `event.target.closest('[data-id]')?.dataset.id` — See [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Comment: did you know that `data-xxx` attributes are available using `element.dataset.xxx` - perhaps not your issue, but it's cleaner looking code :p